# How do I package a web fragment in a jar with Netbeans and Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, package, meta-inf

When selecting a new maven project from the Netbeans New Project Menu, there is the option to create a Web Application, or a Standalone Application. I'd like to create a Class Library for use with a Web Application.

How would you recommend I go about this. I see the new Servlet 3.0 Web Fragments need to be put into the META-INF folder and saved as web-fragment.xml. I'm not too sure where I'd create this directory if I'm packing a JAR and a WAR.

Some insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to start from Maven POM and then import the project to Netbeans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create either Java application or Web Application. Just place the META-INF folder in the src/main/resources folder. and place web-fragment.xml directly under it. You can also place any images,css or javascript files in META-INF/resources folder. So when the application you are deploying this for will look in the WEB-INF/lib folder and load all the META-INF contents of the jar onto the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

when generating the .war file with standard maven settings (no special config of maven-plugin-war) the `web-fragment.xml` should found in the `/META-INF` dir of the generated JAR file inside the WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib` dir.

in our case the `web-fragment.xml` was not in this dir but in the WAR's `/META-INF` dir, which is the wrong place